# Tablas con esquinas redondeadas o es un DIV?? no puedo resolver

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

https://transportespulgar.cl/fin.jpg

Favor alguien me podria ayudar hacer esos cuadros, he intentado durante horas, y que sea responsive!! les agradecería que siempre algo me queda mal...
saludos,
RAMCHile!

Comment: Aquí no resolvemos tareas, en caso de que tengas un error, y no estés atascado, estaremos encantados de ayudarte, siempre y cuando la pregunta sea específica y proporciones suficiente detalle al respecto

Comment: gracias entiendo tengo el codigo, y los errores,,, vale!

Answer (score -5):

espero te sirva, solo guiate del codigo no pongas cuidado a carpetas ni de mas archivos

[image: codigo css]

[image: html]

[image: index]

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio..